# Python Dataframes - Bloomberg API Bulk Fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api, bloomberg

```
df = pd.DataFrame(blp.bdp(tickers='AAPL US Equity', flds=['DVD_CRNCY']))
df.head()
```

The above works well. However, if I try another field with bulk data (like DVD_HIST_ALL) - I get an error.

```
f = pd.DataFrame(blp.bdp(tickers='AAPL US Equity', flds=['DVD_HIST_ALL']))
df.head()
```

How to process this bulk data correctly?

Comment: There is really not enough information to answer this.

Comment: I don't know what python library you are using but I suspect you need to use a different function for bulk data, typically `bds` instead of `bdp`.

Comment: assylias, thanks very much!

Comment: no need to use `pd.DataFrame` for your purpose

Comment: Assuming you are using xbbg, the documentation for bds has a very similar query. `blp.bds('AAPL US Equity', 'DVD_Hist_All', DVD_Start_Dt='20180101', DVD_End_Dt='20180531')` The return comes as a dataframe already. https://xbbg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/